# Express middleware Passport not responding unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

**Passport**

```
passport.use('jwt', new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.where({id: jwt_payload.id}).fetch().then(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return done(err, false);
    });
}));
```

**Example 2**
This works but when the JWT is not set, I get `res = null` when I think I should be getting an `401` response.

```
app.get('/user', getProfile);
getProfile = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
        if(user) {
            res.json(user);
        } else {
            res.json(err);
        }
    })(res, req, next);
};
```

**Example 2**
When the JWT is not set then I get the correct `401` response but if it is set I can't get `user` returned because `res` doesn't exist.

```
app.get('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, getProfile);
getProfile = function(err, user) {
    if(user) {
        res.json(user); 
    } else {
            res.json(err);
    }
};
```

So how do I pass res into this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example 1

In your first example, it looks like you've just mixed up the order of `req` and `res` in your function call. It should be

```
})(req, res, next);
```

not

```
})(res, req, next);
```

#### Example 2

In your second example, I think you're using the callback to `passport.authenticate` incorrectly.

The `passport.authenticate` method is just middleware to be called before your actual route gets hit. Its callback does not replace the regular route callback function you would define to handle sending a response - you still need to provide a route callback after the middleware.

```
app.get('/user',
passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(req.user);
});
```

The `authenticate` method should handle responding with an appropriate status code if the user was not authenticated, so you can safely call `req.user` in your route callback and know the user is authenticated.